# Issue in Dynamic DropDownList Using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Refer to the attached Images.
I am using Dynamic DropDownList for Displaying Country, State & City in my Add_New Organization Form. I am retrieving the DropDownList Items from the SQL DataBase.

The Problem is that when I click the submit button it stores the ID's into the database instead of Text of DropDownList Items.

Please help me I have tried many solutions but problem is still there. 
Controller For Saving Data:

```
 [HttpPost]
 Public ActionResult Addnew(Organiztioninfo org)
 {
    db.Organiztioninfoes.Add(org);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
 }
 //Organization Info is my table name. I am using Entity Framework
```

Controller For Retrieving Country List Data form DB:

```
 Public JsonResult Details()
 {

 var country = db.countries.ToList();
//countries is database table name holding list of countries
List<SelectListItems> licountry = new List<SelectListItems>();
foreach(var u in country)
{

  licountry.Add(new SelectListItems{Text = u.Name, Value= u.ID.ToString()});
}

  return Json(new SelectList(licountry, "Value", "Text", 
 JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet ))
 }
 //Same Methods are implemented for populating State & Cities list..
```

[DropDownList-Code||](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKmQ.png)
[J Query-Dynamic List||](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Wfs.png)

Comment: Where is the code which saves data to the database? Are you saving the data in the same tables?

Comment: I have a controller method which is called on HTTP POST Request..

Comment: Can you share that code? Update the original post with the code... do not share code in comments please..

Comment: Please check now. I have wrote the original code which saves data to the database

Comment: The table `Organiztioninfo` has columns for Country,State and City which datatype `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: Yes the data type is NVARCHAR.

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted below?

Comment: It's much better if you include the code in the question using the `{}` button instead of posting images via an external image hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is the `SelectedValue` property of dropdown is being assigned to the properties of `Organiztioninfo` class object. And `Value` property of dropdown list are bound to the `Id` of `Country`, `State` and `City` as shown in `J Query-Dynamic List` image.

If you do not want the `Id` to be assigned, you should set the`Value` to `data.Text` when you are creating dropdown lists dynamically as following.

```
//For country
$("#country").appened('<option value="' + data.Text + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');

//For States
$("#province").appened('<option value="' + state.Text + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');

// For city (I assume that the dataitem name is 'city' here.
$("#city").appened('<option value="' + city.Text + '">' + city.Text + '</option>');
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried this solution. But in my Form when a user selects Country Option from a DropDownList. JQuery script populates the State Items on the basis of Country Item_ID which user has selected. So if we change the data.Value into data.Text. then JQuery wont be able to locate the record for that particular Country Item.

Comment: ok.. got it.. Makes sense... but why you want to store names instead of Id?  What if name of a country or states changes later? You will have invalid data in OrganizationInfo table... I am sure you have thought about it.

Comment: I think I know other way to solve this by using hidden fields... Give me some time. I will update my answer.. By that time can you share code which populates states based on selected country?